# Instantons and Borel Resummation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, research-level, renormalization, instantons

As explained in Weinberg's *The Quantum Theory of Fields, Volume 2, Chapter 20.7 Renormalons*, instantons are a known source of poles in the Borel transform of the perturbative series. These poles are on the negative real axis, and the series remains Borel-summable as long as the coupling constant is not too large.

However, instantons are objects in the *Euclidean* version of QFT. What's the significance of the above Borel resummation in the Minkowski theory?

Comment: You seem to be thinking that the perturbation theory of the Euclidean and Minkowskian theories are unrelated, but in fact they are related.  I suppose a good analogy here is complex analysis, where you can compute an integral by contour deformation and the position of the poles in complex plane is important.

Comment: @SidiousLord: good point. But I'm more interested in seeing an application in a specific problem, which Weinberg's book hasn't done.

Comment: it would be easier to realize that Instantons are tunneling solutions to the physical Minkowski theory, and that the Euclideanization is a trick to streamline the WKB method in field theory.

Comment: See [this](https://inspirehep.net/record/1117899) and related work.